# Haskell HasCallStack unexpected behavior

Tags: haskell, ghc, stack-trace

The following is a simplification of a pretty common pattern we have, where you have some retry combinator wrapping an IO operation. I would like to have some stack traces so I added the `HasCallStack` constraint but the resulting stacktrace was not really satisfactory:

```hs
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import GHC.Stack

httpCall :: HasCallStack => IO ()
httpCall = do
  putStrLn $ prettyCallStack callStack
  print "http resolved"

retry :: HasCallStack => IO () -> IO ()
retry op =
  forM_ [1] $ \i ->
    op

main :: IO ()
main = retry httpCall
```

stacktrace:

```
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  httpCall, called at main.hs:16:14 in main:Main
"http resolved"
```

I assumed the `HasCallStack` constraint gets resolved in `main` to fit the argument type of `retry` so I added the constraint to the argument type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import GHC.Stack

httpCall :: HasCallStack => IO ()
httpCall = do
  putStrLn $ prettyCallStack callStack
  print "http resolved"

retry :: HasCallStack => (HasCallStack => IO()) -> IO () -- NOTICE the constraint in the argument
retry op =
  forM_ [1] $ \i ->
    op

main :: IO ()
main = retry httpCall
```

Now the stacktrace has 2 more entries both of them quite surprising:

```
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  httpCall, called at main.hs:17:14 in main:Main
  op, called at main.hs:14:5 in main:Main
  retry, called at main.hs:17:8 in main:Main
"http resolved"
```

### Problems

1. `httpCall` reports it was called from `main` (line 17)
2. `op` reports the correct line but is quite unexpected to see it in the stacktrace to begin with.

I expected something along the lines of:

```
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  httpCall, called at main.hs:14:5 in main:Main
  retry, called at main.hs:17:8 in main:Main
"http resolved"
```

Comment: This happens (I guess) because `op` and `httpCall` are not functions, so GHC has to decide where is the "call point", the point where the "call" is logged into the stack trace. This is where the constraint is resolved by type inference, which might be not so intuitive. Consider to disambiguate this by having `httpCall :: HasCallStack => () -> IO ()`, just for the sake of experimenting, and see if the result is more intuitive.

Comment: If [this](https://repl.it/repls/BlondBothTransversals) is what you meant, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: here's the above code as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fghibellini/680c45e4a6660e00a0a697fb742502da) (I can't freeze the repl.it code)

Answer (score 1):

For both problems 1 and 2, note that `HasCallStack` call stacks are fundamentally "lexical".

Specifically, with respect to "problem 1", the call site (function name and line number) information in the call stack is based on where syntactically in the program the called function appears, not the line of code that actually forces the call to be made.  So, the reason `httpCall` is shown to be called from line 17 and not line 14 is because the literal program text "`httpCall`" appears on line 17.  Similarly for "problem 2", the thing called on line 14 appears lexically as `op`, not `httpCall`, so that's how it appears in the call stack.

With respect to the behavior of your programs:

In your first program, the `HasCallStack` constraints on `retry` and `httpCall` in `main` are resolved by pushing appropriate call entries (with lexical call site information) onto an empty call stack (because `main` provides no `HasCallStack` instance itself).  If we made the call stack argument explicit, the code would look something like:

```
httpCall :: CallStack -> IO ()
httpCall callStack = do
  putStrLn $ prettyCallStack callStack
  print "http resolved"

retry :: CallStack -> IO () -> IO ()
retry callStack op =
  forM_ [1] $ \i ->
    op

main :: IO ()
main = retry (push1 emptyCallStack) (httpCall (push2 emptyCallStack))
  where push1 = pushCallStack ("retry", SrcLoc "" "" "" 15 7 15 11)
        push2 = pushCallStack ("httpCall", SrcLoc "" "" "" 15 13 15 20)
```

Note that the `callStack` argument to `retry` that records the `retry` call (`push1`) isn't actually used.  When `httpCall` is evaluated, it gets passed `push2 emptyCallStack` which generates a single entry for the `httpCall` call in `main`.

I think all that is more or less what you assumed was happening (i.e., the `HasCallStack` constraint gets resolved in main to fit the argument type of `retry`).

In your second program, something interesting happens that perhaps isn't well documented.  The `retry` call is treated the same way as before, but the `httpCall` -- because it is typed as `HasCallStack => IO ()` instead of `IO ()` -- produces code that expects an instance to be in scope instead of resolving the instance immediately.  With explicit call stack arguments, the code generated for `retry` and `main` would now look something like:

```
retry :: CallStack -> (CallStack -> IO ()) -> IO ()
retry callStack op =
  forM_ [1] $ \i ->
    op (push3 callStack)
  where push3 = pushCallStack ("op", SrcLoc "" "" "" 14 4 14 6)

main :: IO ()
main = retry (push1 emptyCallStack) (\callStack -> httpCall (push2 callStack))
  where push1 = pushCallStack ("retry", SrcLoc "" "" "" 17 7 17 11)
        push2 = pushCallStack ("httpCall", SrcLoc "" "" "" 17 13 17 20)
```

The result is that `httpCall` actually gets `push2 $ push3 $ push1 emptyCallStack` as its argument, so you see the three entries for `httpCall`, `op`, and `retry` in that order.